# Query to view the jsonb data column with dynamic value in tabular form in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In "snapshot" table I have rows in following order

```
id(uuid) || snapShotId(uuid) || resultData(jsonb) || createdAt(timestamp)
```

The data in "resultData" column is of type jsonb and it is storing dynamic data like this:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'Ram', age: 23, }]
[{id:2, title: 'Some title', release_year: '1995'}, {id:3, title: 'Some title 1', release_year: '1996'}]
[{id:4, email: 'hello@gmail.com'}]
```

what i wanted is to write a query  to view the column of "resultData" column which has dynamic value in table format:

Result will look like this:

```
**id || name || age || title || email || release_year**

1  || Ram  || 23  ||   null       ||   null   || null
2  || null || null || some title  || null || 1995
3  || null || null || some title 1 || null || 1996
4  || null  || null || null  || hello@gmail.com || null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements` for that:

```
select r.item ->> 'id' as id,
       r.item ->> 'name' as name,
       r.item ->> 'age' as age,
       r.item ->> 'title' as title, 
       r.item ->> 'email' as email,
       r.item ->> 'release_year' as release_year
from snapshot
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(result_data) as r(item)
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=40a78b4cae2b54b94e9c8ae280f3b8b1)

Comment: The data in the column would be dynamic and can have any key and value.. So we can't query like above you mentioned.  Query must know the value, we without specifying it.

Comment: @SabinBogati: it's impossible to have "dynamic columns". One restriction of the SQL language is that all columns of a query (including their data types) must be known _before_ the query is started (i.e. when parsing the SQL).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `JSONB_POPULATE_RECORDSET()` function

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM snapshot
 CROSS JOIN JSONB_POPULATE_RECORDSET( NULL::record, jsdata )
         AS t( id    INT        , name  VARCHAR(80), age          INT, 
               title VARCHAR(80), email VARCHAR(80), release_year INT )
```

after fixing the syntax for the current JSON values by properly (*double*)quoting them.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b283bc58f334d6425189424bb19bdcf1)</kbd>

Comment: The data in the column would be dynamic and can have any key and value.. So we can't query like above you mentioned.  Query must know the value, we without specifying it.